# HBase: how to filter by "key not start with"

Tags: filter, hbase

using *PrefixFilter("word")* it is possible to filter all keys which start with "word".
I am trying to get the opposite, all key which not start with "word".

Is it a filter which ,match to my requirement?
If I will need to create a Filter from my own, will it work? ( I am not sure if the HBase scanner supports new filters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to achieve the same behavior using *RowFilter* and *RegexStringComparator* classes
i.e:

```
RowFilter prefixFilter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL,
 new RegexStringComparator("word"+"[\\S]+"));
```